# Use custom local stored font with WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, font-face, wkwebview

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

I imported a font called `Blastimo.ttf` to my Xcode project by drag and drop it to the files list on the left side of Xcode.

I enabled `Target Membership`.

I added `Fonts provided by application` > `Item 0` : `Blastimo.ttf` to `Info.plist`.

Now I can use this font for e.g. labels. This is working.

I also want to use this font in my `WKWebView` like this:

```
let html = """
        <html>
        <body>
        <head>
        <style>
        @font-face
        {
            font-family: 'Blastimo';
            src: local('Blastimo'), url('Blastimo.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <h1 style="font-family:'Blastimo';font-size:50px;">This is my test!</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

But this is not working, the standard font gets loaded.

The html code itself is working with the font `Blastimo.ttf`. I tested it on my web server.

But it's not working in `WKWebView`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to replace:

`webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)`

by

`webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)`